# Calling seperate theano functions with same inputs?

Tags: theano

I have something like this:

```
    x=T.matrix('x')
    params = [self.W, self.b1, self.b2]
    hidden = self.activation_function(T.dot(x, self.W)+self.b1)
    output = T.dot(hidden,T.transpose(self.W))+self.b2
    output = self.output_function(output)

    L = -T.sum(x*T.log(output) + (1-x)*T.log(1-output), axis=1)
    cost=L.mean()       
    th_train = th.function(inputs=[index], outputs=[cost], updates=updates,
                        givens={x:self.X[index:index+mini_batch_size,:]})
```

This is working fine. I would now like to see what the mean of the hidden units is. I tried adding this before the line where `L = -T.sum...` is declared:

```
    hm = T.mean(hidden)
    hidden_mean_func = th.function(inputs=[hm], outputs=[hm], name="hidden_mean_function_printer")
    print hidden_mean_func(hm)
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "hidden_mean_function_printer"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?')`

I really have two questions: 1) Why can't I do this? 2) What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are giving him the function as input. If you use your array/matrix of hidden units instead the code should work.

```
hidden_mean_func = th.function(inputs=[hidden], outputs=[hm], name="hidden_mean_function_printer")
print hidden_mean_func(hidden)
```